# How to get host name in flutter for windows?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I am working on a flutter application that connects to the MQTT client on the desktop it is opened on. I want to dynamically get the host name of the desktop and connect to it instead of the user having to enter it manually.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform, stdout;

void main() {
  // Get the hostname as a string.
  String hostname = Platform.localHostname;
  
}
```